# Pdfsharp lost visual brush in background of label

Tags: wpf, background, pdfsharp, visualbrush, fixeddocument

My WPF app has a label, the background is visual brush, the brush contains a text"-" ; I use pdfsharp to convert `fixeddocument` to pdf, but strange things happen, some texts are lost, some are at wrong positions; in my WPF app every label has "-" at center. does anyone face this problem too? How can I fix it? 
I am using Pdfsharp 1.31[image: actual][image: expect]

Comment: Please post some code with your question, so we can have a clear view of what you are talking about  ^^

Comment: I add the image, Pdfsharp supported for rendering the background visual brush?